# GLMM in SPSS: what does significance of the fixed coefficients mean?

Tags: statistical-significance, spss, regression-coefficients, glmm

I conducted a GLMM analysis in SPSS with `y~a+b+a*b`.

The output result contains two tables:

1. the fixed effects, for which the main effects and the interaction are significant;
2. the fixed coefficients, for which the significance changes according to the order of `a`, `b` and `a*b` in the model.

My questions are:

How do I interpret the fixed coefficients? (Are they important for inferring conclusions?)

What does their significance mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "the significance changes according to the order of `a`, `b` and `a*b` in the model"? Is that `a`, `b` and `a*b` have different p-values? Or the p-values will change if you change the order of `a`, `b` and `a*b` in the model setting?

Answer (score 1):

The fixed coefficients in GLMM are **subject specific** estimates, which mean the association between $X$ (the predictors) and $Y$ (the outcome, refer to the latent one in nonlinear models) holding constant the random effects, and it describes how an individual's mean of outcome depends on the predictors. You can find the clarification of subject specific and population average estimates [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59137/subject-specific-vs-population-average-predictions/68531#68531).

The importance of fixed coefficients depends on your goal of analysis. The fixed effects are often the focus, unless you are interested in the individual trajectories (random effects) or the scale (variance) of the random effects.

The significance here (mostly based on $z$-test) has the same meaning as that in other tests, which means that you can reject the null hypothesis that fixed coefficient $\beta=0$.